# Need Help with Flow for a sharepoint list

Tags: power-automate, flow

I have created a flow with a conditon
CONDITION if Company Name = CACI, Inc., send email with attachment.  It only is successful for the "yes" side.  I have read online for hours and not sure what I am doing wrong.  I know how to use SP Designer with previous wf conditions, etc. but this is not apparent to me.

[image]

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it looks like you are not actually checking if Comapny Name = "CACI, Inc.", it looks like you are comparing if the value of the Company Name field equals the value of the Company Name field, which will always eveluate to true.

Comment: How would i update that?  thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are comparing the `Company Name` field value to itself, which will always evaluate to `true`.

You need to type in the specific value you want to check for.  In this case, you are saying that you want to check if the `Company Name` value is specifically

> CACI, Inc.

To do that, just type that value in on the right side of the comparison:

[image: screnshot of Flow]

Comment: Firstly, I really appreciate your help - I did exactly that initially but i still couldn't get the action under "no" to work...so I tried this way based on videos, either way I can only get the actions under "Yes" to work

Comment: No sure what to tell you there... I don't know what kind of field your "Company Name" field is or if you have to do some other kind of comparison. For my example here I set it up as just a plain text field, and I did test my Flow and was able to get it to take both the "Yes" and "No" branches.  My guess is that if it is a Text field or a Choice field it should work with just the straight comparison, but if it is a Lookup field you may need to do some additional stuff to get the comparisoon to work.

Comment: Yes it is a choice field....but thank you again!